# Strings read from Core Data gets returned inside ( ), how do I access the string without the ( )?

Tags: ios, core-data

I use the following code to get data from my persistent storage and assign the output to some text fields

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

// Fetch the itemDetails from persistent data store
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"TillData"];
NSPredicate *predicateItemId =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemId==%@", _transactionDetailViewItemIdTxt.text];
NSPredicate *predicateBarCode =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"noos14 LIKE %@", _transactionDetailViewBarCodeTxt.text];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicateItemId, predicateBarCode]];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
self.itemInfo = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];
fetchRequest = nil;

if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
    NSLog(@"TransactionDetailView:transactionDetailViewItemLookupBtn_Pressed:fetchRequest:error %@", error);
    NSLog(@"TransactionDetailView:transactionDetailViewItemLookupBtn_Pressed:self.itemInfo.itemId holds %@", [self.itemInfo valueForKey:@"itemId"]);
    NSLog(@"TransactionDetailView:transactionDetailViewItemLookupBtn_Pressed:self.itemInfo.noos14 holds %@", [self.itemInfo valueForKey:@"noos14"]);
}

[self.transactionDetailViewItemIdTxt setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.itemInfo valueForKey:@"itemId"]]];
[self.transactionDetailViewBarCodeTxt setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.itemInfo valueForKey:@"noos14"]]];
```

The debug output tells me I am getting the correct values back as follows

```
TransactionDetailView:transactionDetailViewItemLookupBtn_Pressed:self.itemInfo.itemId holds (
    101064025138011
)
2016-11-26 00:04:12.428 NWMobileTill[2282:87496] TransactionDetailView:transactionDetailViewItemLookupBtn_Pressed:self.itemInfo.noos14 holds (
    "09258384394951,09258387434951"
)
```

As you can see the returned values are enclosed in (), I thought that was simply the debug output, but in fact those () are also there when I assign the strings to text fields which of course makes no sense, meaning I end up with strings in my UITextFields that looks like (   fooo  )

Why is my data enclosed in those parentheses and how do I access the actual values without the parentheses? Rest assured the actual data in the DB is NOT enclosed in ( )

Answer (score 0):

The `executeFetchRequest:error:` method returns an `NSArray`. When you call `valueForKey:` on an array, the result is **also** an array. And finally, when you use an `NSArray` where a string is expected the default `description` method is called which, on `NSArray`, includes the parentheses and comma(s) between elements.

So in short: you're getting these because you're trying to use an array like a string, and `NSArray` is trying to help you.

Updated: You need to pick the single string out of the array instead of using the array directly. You need to do this even though the array only contains one element, because it's still an `NSArray`.

Comment: But how can I know what value is at which index in the array if I cannot use some sort of valueForKey on the array? for example how can I know that itemId is at [0,0] because thats what it seems for be?

Comment: I understand what I need to do, I just don't understand how I can access the string without knowing its index in the first place, fetchRequest returns an array that I am putting in another array meaning I have an array within and array, I don't get how I can know how to access the object where I have the itemId? I am new to this so I understand the theory and I have tried to translate it into code but not been successful, a brief example would be a great help

Comment: it didn't let me edit, I tried this already and it don't work

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working using this code where kalle is the array returned from the fetch request and I also set the fetchrequest to return a NSDict instead of an array like this

```
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;



NSString *pelle = nil;
    NSString *egg = nil;

    for (id kalle in item) {
        pelle = [kalle valueForKey:@"itemId"];
        egg = [kalle valueForKey:@"noos14"];
    }
```